# IAM role inside SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

How to create an IAM role inside a SAM template likewise I did in SAM package.
I tried this as following:

```
"lambdaFunctionRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "lambda.amazonaws.com",
                  "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
          ]
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          {
            "Ref": "lambdaBasePolicy"
          }
        ],
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "root",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                    "logs:PutLogEvents"
                  ],
                  "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
                },
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "s3:*",
                    "dynamodb:*",
                    "iam:ListRoles",
                    "ses:*",
                    "events:*"
                  ],
                  "Resource": "*"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

It throws me an error : com.amazonaws.serverlessappsrepo.template.InvalidTemplateException: Resource with name [lambdaFunctionRole] is invalid. AWS::Serverless::Role is not a supported Serverless Apps Repository Type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When publishing to the Serverless app repo, you need to take care to use only the [supported resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverlessrepo/latest/devguide/using-aws-sam.html#supported-resources-for-serverlessrepo) in you SAM template.

In your case, you can skip creating the `lambdaFunctionRole` as a standalone resource and just create it inline in your function resource definition.

```
"lambdaFunction": {
  "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
  "Policies": [
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "s3:*",
            "dynamodb:*",
            "iam:ListRoles",
            "ses:*",
            "events:*"
          ],
          "Resource": "*"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that I've only copied the `PolicyDocument` part of the Policies in the Role. See the Policies section in the [SAM spec](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md).